# How can i pass a json encoded response to another page?

Tags: php, json

On page contacts.php i have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="request.php">
    <label for="bike">Enter Model: </label>
    <input type="text" name="bike" value=''/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

On page request.php i have this code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['bike']))
{
//
$name=$_POST['bike'];
$price=get_price($name);

if (empty($price))

deliver_response(200,"Bike Not Found",NULL);

else
deliver_response(200,"Bike Found",$price);
}
else
{
deliver_response(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);
}

function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");  
$response['status']=$status;
$response['status_message']=$status_message;
$response['data']=$data;

$json_response=json_encode($response);
echo $json_response;

}
```

This echos out a json formatted response on the page "request.php". 
My question is, how can i pass that response ($json_response) back to the "contacts.php" page?

Here is my answer:

```
 $json_response=json_encode($response);
 $_SESSION['bike']=$json_response;
 header('Location:contacts.php');
```

And then on contacts.php;

```
 echo $_SESSION['bike'];
```

Comment: You could make use of sessions.

Comment: I cannot put a variable in a session?

Comment: You need to make sure your form does not submit. Make a json call to request.php view javascript.

Comment: Use AJAX. It really is the bee's knees.

Comment: Done it. Thanks.
  $json_response=json_encode($response);
  $_SESSION['bike']=$json_response;
  header('Location:contacts.php');

Answer (score 0):

take the code on your request.php page and put it into top of the page running the form.  Then change action="request.php" to action="contacts.php"